# Netsuite restlet: src property must be a valid json object

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm attempting to write a RESTlet script to pull over some work order data to another web application (Tulip), but when I attempt to run the script, I receive the following error output:
"src property must be a valid json object"

My get request does have the "Content-Type: application/json" header.

Here is the script I'm attempting to run for reference (the script is very basic at the moment as I just try to figure this all out):

```
function getWOSoftLock(){

var WOColumns = new Array();

WOColumns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid');
WOColumns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('status');

var filter = new nlobjSearchFilter(
  'status',
  null,
  'is',
  'Released',
  null
);

var dataoutput = nlapiSearchRecord(
    'workorder',
    null,
    filter,
    WOColumns
);

return dataoutput

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I'm new at this. If I do not include the Content-Type: application/json header, I receive "Invalid data format. You should return text."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SS1 search results were funny beasts and did not used to serialize properly.

You should do something like:

```js
function getWOSoftLock() {


    var dataoutput = nlapiSearchRecord(
        'workorder',
        null,
        new nlobjSearchFilter('status', null, 'is', 'Released'),
        [
            new nlobjSearchColumn('tranid'),
            new nlobjSearchColumn('status')
        ]
    );

    if(!dataoutpout) {
        nlapiLogExecution('AUDIT', 'No released work orders');
        return [];
    }

    return dataoutput.map(function(res){
        return {
            tranid:res.getValue('tranid'),
            status:res.getValue('status')
        };
    });

}
```